# sqlalchemy queries not fetching right data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a basic query that I run over and over at each 2 minutes to extract all records that have a flag set to 1/true etc.

If I run the script from the command and I have a record with the flag set it extracts it then, if I go to mysql directly and re-set that flag to true/1 the next time (2 minutes) the query is executed the record is not found.

I have enabled the queries executed to be printed out to my console and if I execute the query directly into mysql I can see the record showing up. Why isnt sqlalchemy finding it?

Here's my config:

```
engine = create_engine( config.DATABASE_URI, pool_recycle=1800 )
metadata = MetaData()
db_session = scoped_session( sessionmaker( bind = engine, 
                                           autoflush = True, 
                                           autocommit = False ) )
```

Comment: why do I have to commit whatever I add through mysql admin? Isn't the select supposed to be selecting what's in the database?

Comment: you cannot select something in another transaction until it has been committed by the first transaction.

Comment: I'm not commiting anything. I'm updating the values directly from mysql using the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be related to the scoped session. With this type of session, a session is bind to every server thread.. what framework are you using?

Comment: Ensure, at the end of every request, the db session is closed to avoid using old sessions attached to other threads.

Comment: make a response from this and I'll give you the accept. I was looping continuously and selecting the results at every 2 minutes but not closing down the session in between so that was it.